# DefaultGetServlet No renderer for extension html cannot render resource JcrNodeResource

Tags: aem, sling

After several deployment to AEM instance (6.5) in error.log:
`org.apache.sling.servlets.get.impl.DefaultGetServlet No renderer for extension html, cannot render resource JcrNodeResource,`
Did anyone find the fix on this issue?

Comment: Did you find a workaround or the root cause?

Comment: @ronnyfm, sandroconte did anyone of you find any root cause?

Answer (score 0):

This issue can be caused because DefaultGetServlet OSGI bundle **failed to start or has a wrong configuration**. Try the following:

1. Check Sling GET servlet configuration at Web Console accessing URL ->

   - *http://{host}:{port}/system/console/configMgr/org.apache.sling.servlets.get.DefaultGetServlet*
   - Make sure that **Enable JSON** and **Enable XML** are selected
2. Restart OSGI bundles from Web Console > System Information tab, or acces directly through URL ->

   - *http://{host}:{port}/system/console/vmstat*
   - **Click Restart button**

[image]

Notes from [AEM forum answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4TTXe.png) by Jaideep Brar:

> **Restarting** from **vmstat** will trigger a restart of all the bundles. So,
> if you just wanted to *refresh the bundles*, you can do that.
>
> That said, **it does not completely stop the AEM instance** as the PID is
> still active in the background after you trigger a "Stop" from vmstat.
>
> Lastly, this does not cause any corruption/issues but ***you should not
> be using this to stop the instance*** as PID will be active even if you
> stop the Sling framework.